# Getting "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" when trying to register broadcast receiver of embedded apk

Tags: java, android, dynamic, reflection

My app has an embedded APK, I need to register a `BroadcastReceiver` in the inner APK from my main APK.

The inner APK is not to be installed on the system; I must load it dynamically. So, I'm using reflection to call a method in the inner APK which has code to register the `BroadcastReceiver`. This receiver of inner APK should invoke for related broadcast.

I'm getting an error while trying to register the `BroadcastReceiver`. Is it even possible for a `BroadcastReceiver` to be registered in this way, and be fully functional? Exception and code are given below

Error related log:

```
08-24 08:31:26.915: D/MainApp(1957): invoke method
08-24 08:31:26.955: D/InnerApp(1957): Register receiver
08-24 08:31:26.955: W/System.err(1957): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-24 08:31:26.965: W/System.err(1957):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-24 08:31:26.965: W/System.err(1957):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-24 08:31:26.965: W/System.err(1957):     at com.example.ea_mainapp.MainApp.invokeService(MainApp.java:105)
08-24 08:31:26.965: W/System.err(1957):     at com.example.ea_mainapp.MainApp.onCreate(MainApp.java:40)
08-24 08:31:26.965: W/System.err(1957):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
08-24 08:31:26.975: W/System.err(1957):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-24 08:31:26.975: W/System.err(1957):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
08-24 08:31:26.975: W/System.err(1957):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-24 08:31:26.975: W/System.err(1957):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-24 08:31:26.975: W/System.err(1957):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-24 08:31:26.975: W/System.err(1957):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-24 08:31:26.975: W/System.err(1957):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-24 08:31:26.975: W/System.err(1957):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-24 08:31:26.975: W/System.err(1957):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-24 08:31:26.975: W/System.err(1957):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-24 08:31:26.975: W/System.err(1957):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-24 08:31:26.975: W/System.err(1957):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-24 08:31:26.975: W/System.err(1957):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-24 08:31:26.985: W/System.err(1957): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-24 08:31:26.985: W/System.err(1957):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:467)
08-24 08:31:26.985: W/System.err(1957):     at com.example.ea_innerapp.InnerApp.register(InnerApp.java:50)
08-24 08:31:26.985: W/System.err(1957):     ... 18 more`
```

Related code from Main app:

```
// invoke method
Log.d(TAG,"invoke method");

final String apkFile =TARGET_BASE_PATH+"EA_innerApp.apk";
String className = "com.example.ea_innerapp.InnerApp";
String methodToInvoke = "register"; 

final File optimizedDexOutputPath = getDir("outdex", 0);

DexClassLoader dLoader = new DexClassLoader(apkFile,optimizedDexOutputPath.getAbsolutePath(),
                null,ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getParent());

try {
    Class<?> loadedClass = dLoader.loadClass(className);
    Object obj = (Object)loadedClass.newInstance();
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Class noparams[] = {};
    Method m = loadedClass.getMethod(methodToInvoke, noparams);
    Object oNoparams[] = {};
    m.invoke(obj, oNoparams);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {....
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Code of invoked method, "com.example.ea_innerapp.InnerApp.register":

```
Log.d(TAG, "Register receiver");
IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter(); 
filter.addAction("com.example.ea_mainapp.i");
registerReceiver(obj_InnerReceiver,filter);
```

Comment: Did you investigate the inner (cause) NullPointerException? Seemingly the problem somewhere down the call stack from com.example.ea_innerapp.InnerApp.register, but that data is not available in your post.

Comment: @Matjaž Pečan: "com.example.ea_innerapp.InnerApp.register" is the method invoked by main app. Code of this method is given in the post, I'll edit the heading to make it clear. This method has to simply register a broadcast receiver. During my tests, inner app independently works fine, but when I invoke this method of inner apk(not installed on system) then I get that exception on the line where it calls method "registerReceiver" to register receiver

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is, I think it might be related to Context, but I do not know how to fix it

Comment: Since you are invoking it from an inner APK, is there a possibility that something inside it might be null for that reason? You are loading a class, instantiating it and then calling register on it, is it possible that it is missing some references due to that? Maybe you should populate some more fields in it before calling register, where does the obj_InnerReciever reference come from, is it initialized in the constructor?

Comment: "obj_InnerReciever " is defined as a private variable of class "com.example.ea_innerapp.InnerApp.register". Exact statement is "private InnerReceiver obj_InnerReceiver = new InnerReceiver();". I think I should try making it public and instantiating it in constructor.

Comment: I made obj_InnerReceiver public, and instantiated within constructor, but still getting same error.

Comment: @Matjaž Pečan, thanks for the useful hints! :) I have fixed the issue now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have fixed the issue.

**Identification of issue:**

Main section of exception staketrace was

```
08-24 08:31:26.985: W/System.err(1957): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-24 08:31:26.985: W/System.err(1957):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:467)
08-24 08:31:26.985: W/System.err(1957):     at com.example.ea_innerapp.InnerApp.register(InnerApp.java:50)
```

I looked at code of *"android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceive"* to find the main cause. Related code of class *ContextWrapper* is given below

```
464    @Override
465    public Intent registerReceiver(
466        BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter) {
467        return mBase.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
468    }
```

Ref.: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.4_r1-robolectric-1/android/content/ContextWrapper.java#ContextWrapper.0mBase

Error was at line 467, which is `"return mBase.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);"`. Here, *mBase* is object of class *"android.content.Context"*. 
**Value of Context was null** in class *"com.example.ea_innerapp.InnerApp*", since it is class of embedded apk. This is why I was getting exception.

**Solution:**

I needed to provide a Context value. So, I passed *Context of main apk* as argument to *"com.example.ea_innerapp.InnerApp.register"*.

*"com.example.ea_innerapp.InnerApp.register"* was calling "*android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceive"*, which does not receive Context as parameter. So, I directly called *"android.content.Context.registerReceiver"*, using the *Context* provided by main apk. Modified *"com.example.ea_innerapp.InnerApp.register"*  is

```
public void register(Context param_ctx){        
        ......
        param_ctx.registerReceiver(obj_InnerReceiver,filter);   
    }
```

Note that you'll have to save the value of *param_ctx* and use it while un registering receiver as well, otherwise you'll get error. To unregister receiver you'll call

```
ctx.unregisterReceiver(obj_InnerReceiver); // ctx is the value that was passed to "com.example.ea_innerapp.InnerApp.register"
```